# How to center a div vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that I want to center horizontally and vertically.

For the horizontal issue everything is great, but I have a problem with the vertical alignment.

I tried this:

```
#parent {
    display: table;
}

#child {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: i tried google ... thanks for your help

Comment: check my answer to see if it works for you.. @ra_htial .... yeah ages old question, but still a tricky one that should be clarified

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you only have to support browsers that support `transform` (or its vendor prefixed versions), use this one weird old trick to vertically align elements.

```
#child {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

If you have to support older browsers, you can use a combination of these, but they can be a pain due to the differences in rendering `block` vs `table`.

```
#parent {
    display: table;
}

#child {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If your height is fixed and you need to support those really old, pesky browsers...

```
#parent {
   position: relative;
}

#child {
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```

If your height is not fixed, there is a [workaround](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/aeVYD/).

Comment: thanks a lot my friend but that only work if i know what is the #child height ... but it's not always the same, thumb UP !! thanks for your useful answer!!

Comment: @From.ME.to.YOU See the [workaround](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html). Unfortunately, IE6+7 make the extra containers necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Having the parent property as, `display:table` and child property as `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flexbox` to center horizontally or vertically your child `div` inside a parent `div`:

This should be your html:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
      info
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is the `css` with `flexbox`:

```
#parent{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   background: lightgray;
}
#child{
   position: relative;
   background: black;
   padding: 2rem;
   color: white;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Here is de codepen: https://codepen.io/bongardabo/pen/YzZQgaJ

Answer (score 0):

First off, treating non-table markup as tables (with display:table and friends) isn't cross-browser. I don't know which browsers you need to support but certainly IE6 won't do this. But, if your targeted browser *do* all support display:table I can give you some tips.

The vertical centering approach you're looking for (using table layout) depends on having a TD with vertical-align:middle, then inside of that a single block element will vertically center. So I think what you want is:

```
#parent { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
#child { /* nothing necessary, assuming it's a DIV it's already display:block */ }
```

It's ok to use table-cell with no surrounding table-row and table, the browser infers the needed table wrapping elements for you.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way when you don't know the inner div size or whatever, you may use % here and there to fix the "centering" ....

the idea is that your top value is half the height of your child element as to create the centering illusion

Here's the code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
            hello
    </div>
</div>
```

and for the styling:

```
#parent {
   position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:green;
}

#child {
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
    position:relative;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
   background-color:red;
}
```

Here you can see it in action
http://jsfiddle.net/Wabxv/

Comment: note that this will center the div in the available space that is remaining for it (if parent div has some text, this way will center in the remaining space, not the whole parent item size... for that use absolute positioning)